# I want to reset my repository but it is just unstaging

Tags: git, git-reset

I had a repository with just one file 'file2.py' and is committed till now.
Now I have created a new file file3.py and saved it .
I staged the file using 'git add file3.py'
Now i want to make my repository as it was in the latest commit that is before file3.py was created.
I have used 'git reset HEAD file3.py' but it is just unstaging the staged step but not removing the file file3.py.

visha@LAPTOP-ID7C05LT MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ code file3.py**

MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
file3.py
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)**

MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ git add file3.py**

MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git restore --staged ..." to unstage)
new file:   file3.py**

MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ git reset HEAD file3.py**

MINGW64 ~/OneDrive/Desktop/checks (master)

**$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
file3.py
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)**

Why is it not removing file3.py ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `file3.py` is untracked, then there's nothing git can do to remove it. You should instead just remove it locally: `rm file3.py`

Comment: can't i get it to the latest commit where file3.py does not exist?

Comment: Not if you never committed it, no

Comment: i did commit when file2.py only exist, but not file3.py.
sry if i am asking a lot of questions.

Comment: exactly. So there is no commit which contains file.py, so you'll have to remove it manually, there's nothing git can do

Answer (score 0):

actually `git clean` removes untracked files; I find it pretty useful at times